# What is best practice when storing RFC3339 time in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, go, time, unix-timestamp, google-cloud-sql

I have data in a Google Cloud Datastore NoSQL database. The objects in this database contain fields of [type `Time.time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time), specifically RFC3339 format (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD). I am moving some of this data into a Google Cloud SQL database and I am wondering what is considered best practice when storing RFC3339 formatted time data in a MySQL database.

[This post](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2014/01/30/timestamps-in-mysql/) strongly suggests the following:

> All date and time columns shall be `INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`, and shall
>   store a Unix timestamp in UTC.

So, should I just make use of [Golang's `func (t Time) Unix()`](https://godoc.org/time#Time.Unix) and store the data that way? What are some alternative approaches to storing the data? What kinds of issues might I run into if I don't heed the poster's advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the `go-sql-driver/mysql` you can ask the driver to scan DATE and DATETIME automatically to time.Time, by adding `parseTime=true` to your connection string.

See https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#timetime-support

Example code:

```
db, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "root:@/?parseTime=true")

var myTime time.Time
row, err := db.QueryRow("SELECT current_timestamp()")

row.Scan(&myTime)
fmt.Println(myTime)
```